# Redirecting to App Store from iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, http, redirect

Is it possible to deep link straight to the App Store from Safari on iOS to bypass this confirmation alert?

Here's the situation I want: user taps on website.com/download from a text message, it opens in Safari then redirect immediately to the App Store with no "Open in App Store" confirmation.

```
if( isMobile.iOS() ) {
    window.location = "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tracks-video-conversations/id991383515?mt=8";  
}
```

I've seen this work on iOS by tapping this link through iMessage: http://get.vine.co, and https://lyft.com/app

I also tried a php header redirect but still get the confirmation alert.

```
<?php header('Location: itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tracks-video-conversations/id991383515?mt=8'); ?>
```

*Here is the image of what I'm seeing, that I don't want to see.*

[image]

Comment: No. It is not possible on stock iOS.

Comment: I'm seeing it work on get.vine.co, and lyft.com/app

Comment: Only when tapped on through iMessage though. It opens in safari briefly then goes to app store